# apt-get install fails because of libmagic1

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

my apt-get install is failing because of following error with respect to libmagic1.   My Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS.  Can you please help if anyone aware of it?   I need to fix this to update some packages which are needed for my work.

```
~# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Correcting dependencies... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libblas-dev patchutils libncurses5-dev po-debconf intltool-debian libreadline6-dev intltool liblapack-dev libtinfo-dev python-scour lesstif2 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
  thunderbird-globalmenu html2text libmail-sendmail-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl dpatch libbz2-dev libreadline-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmagic1

The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmagic1

1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 215 not upgraded.
305 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/218 kB of archives.

After this operation, 5,120 B of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y

(Reading database ... 263712 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libmagic1 5.09-2 (using .../libmagic1_5.09-2ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmagic1 ...
dpkg: warning: libmagic1: conffile 'etc/magic' is not a plain file or symlink (= '/usr/share/file/magic')
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagic1_5.09-2ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 unable to open '/etc/magic.dpkg-new': No such file or directory

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagic1_5.09-2ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` first ?

Answer (score 0):

check `/etc/magic` and see if that file exists also check `/usr/share/file/magic` folder exists

If /etc/magic doesn't exist use the following

```
sudo touch /etc/magic
```

If the usr/share/file/magic folder doesn't exist use the following

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/file/magic
```

Then try again .. this should solve the issue or at least come up with something else to go on